# If $f$ continuous and $[f(x_1)+...+f(x_n)]/n=f([x_1+...+x_n]/n)$ then $f$ linear

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, functions, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a continuous function $\mathbb{R}\to 
\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$,

$[f(x_1)+...+f(x_n)]/n=f([x_1+...+x_n]/n)$

I conjecture that $f$ must be linear.

---

I have found a weird geometric proof of this for $n=2$ and $n=3$, but it's not very elegant and I'm not sure if it generalizes easily to higher $n$. Essentially, if $S$ denotes the set of points on the graph of $f$, then for any $n$ points in $S$, their barycenter also lies in $S$; I have shown (for $n=2,3$) that unless $S$ is a line,then $S$ will fail the "vertical line test", contradicting the fact that $S$ is the graph of a *function*.

I have also found a cute counterexample for $n=2$ to the problem statement if $f$ is not required to be continuous.

Anyways, I'm looking for an easy proof of the problem for general $n$.

Comment: Fixing $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ determines the value of $f$ on all rationals whose denominator is a power of $n$, and these are dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Try to show that $f(k_1x_1+k_2x_2+\cdots+k_nx_n)=k_1f(x_1)+k_2f(x_2)+\cdots+k_nf(x_n)$ for $k_i\ge0$ and $k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n=1$.

Comment: I don't exactly know the proper solution to this, but try using $\mathrm{Jensen-Inequality}$.
(The relation of $\lambda_1f(x_1)+\lambda_2f(x_2)+\cdots+\lambda_nf(x_n)$ and $f(\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\cdots+\lambda_nx_n)$, $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots+\lambda_n=1.$)